# Camel/JavaEE - Forwarding post-request URL pattern and posted data from Rest endpoint to following routes/webservices

Tags: java, oracle, web-services, jakarta-ee, apache-camel

We are using camel to route data from our database to several endusers in our company. We have several rest endpoints configured in camel which we are requesting via PL/SQL from our Oracle database.

The rest endpoint may look like `someserver.net/{interfaceId}/{season}/post`. 
From the Oracle db we are sending a comma-seperated list with identifiers which are processed by a java webservice.

I couldn't find any helpful informations how I can use the parameters in the url after forwarding the posted data.
This is how i configured the endpoint:

```
<post uri="/{interfaceId}/{season}/post" produces="text/plain">
   <to uri="direct:postWithSeason" />
</post>
```

After that I want another route which receives the data and the parameters {interfaceId} and {season} and passes them to our webservice which has an url like `someserver.net/hub/xml/{interfaceId}/{season}/post`. The webservice is creating a XML file which is forwarded to the enduser.

The route will be something like

```
<route id="fetchData">
    <from uri="direct:postWithSeason" />
        <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
            <constant>POST</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpUri">
            <simple>http://serverWithWebservice.net/</simple>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpPath">
            <simple>hub/xml/{interfaceId}/{season}/payloadIds</simple>
        </setHeader>
        <to uri="http4:serverWithWebservice.net" />
        <to uri="file:/someDirectory?fileName=someFileName.xml" />
</route>
```

So how can I get the parameters from the URL called by the PL/SQL procedure to the route where the webservice is called along the comma-seperated list of the payloadIds? I am completely fine with building the routes in Java instead of using the XML DSL.

I am working with JavaEE, Camel and HTTP requests only for a few months so I am not familiar with all the basics and I couldn't find any resources providing a solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Camel REST-DSL stores those as Camel Message headers, so you can get then via `${header.interfaceId}` etc, in that simple expression you build

```
<setHeader headerName="CamelHttpPath">
  <simple>hub/xml/${header.interfaceId}/${header.season}/payloadIds</simple>
</setHeader>
```